Kafka 13/13 Brokers Are Down
We are running Kafka 3.1.0 on Kubernetes using Strimzi and a C#(.NET) client that is connecting to this cluster.
When the messages are published to the topic, the error message, "13/13 brokers are down", getting reported randomly (i.e. we see this error only during some writes). There is no data loss - messages are visible on the target topic. The Confluent client library version is 2.4.0.
_producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(producerConfig)
  .SetLogHandler((_, l) => 
  {
      EventLog.WriteEntry(Common.eventLogAlert, $"Create Producer [{l.Level}] : [{l.Message}]", EventLogEntryType.Information, Common.eventIDThrottlingAlert);
  })
  .SetErrorHandler((_, error) =>
  {
      EventLog.WriteEntry(Common.eventLogKafkaProduceAlert, $"Failed to build Kafka producer due to error : {error}", EventLogEntryType.Warning, Common.eventIDThrottlerKafkaProducerAlert);
  })
  .Build();

The error occurs randomly after a period of inactivity, so it is hard to troubleshoot.
Just wondering if anybody had to troubleshoot this error, "brokers are down" when connecting to Kafka using librdkafka library.
